# Custom Dialog Box ... Wait for users input?

Tags: c#

I have a custom dialog box that asks the user for some input. It's combined in a while loop.

Basically it takes a bunch of URL's from a text files, loops through them 1 by 1 and asks the user for their input.

The problem is at the moment is its looping through and showing the dialogs all at once. I want to be able to wait for the users input, when they've pressed submit, continue through the loop onto the next one.

A little stuck.

Comment: How are you showing the dialog? Post your loop code.

Comment: The code I have is a little long to post up. But, it's a foreach(lines in text file){ CustomDialog.show(); }

If I switch it for a MessageBox, it will wait until I press OK to proceed. Thats the sort of thing I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx).

> You can use this method to display a modal dialog box in your application. When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed.

Comment: Works perfect. I will give you this vote, as you used the correct method, even though I figured out from the above poster. Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

For c# (`Getal` is the name of the variable and the `BoxTitle` the name of the Pop-Up).

```
private void enterGetalToolStripMenuItem-Click(object sender, EventArgs e);

Microsoft.Visualbasic.Interaction.Inputbox("Getal ?","BoxTitle","Default Text");
```